# Can I compare object based on the proto buf serialization

Tags: c#, comparison, protobuf-net

I have some model objects that I save in a DB serialized with protobuf. I want to compare the version I will save to the existing one, to avoid to add two times the same version.

Ideally I should

```
byte[] existingBlob = GetFromDBExistingModelObject();
ModelType existingModel = existingBlob.Deserialize();
if (!model.Equals(existingModel))
{
    byte[] serializedModel = model.Serialize();
    Save(serializedModel); //Save in DB the new blob
}
```

However I will have to implement `.Equals` on every model object and this be quite painful. I would like to do

```
byte[] existingBlob = GetFromDBExistingModelObject();
byte[] serializedModel = model.Serialize();
if (!compareBlob(existingBlob, serializedModel)
{
    Save(serializedModel);
}

private bool compareBlob(byte[] existingBlob, byte[] serializedModel)
{
    if (serializedModel.Length != existingBlob.Length)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return !serializedModel.Where((t, i) => t != existingBlob[i]).Any();
}
```

I also do that for performance, because I don't deserialize the `existingBlob`

What do you think of this implementation ? Do you think I can rely on this comparison ? I use protobuf for serialization.

Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

protobuf-net *will* produce a predictable output, but *strictly speaking* that is not guaranteed by the spec;  - there are 2 edge cases (field-order, and sub-normal forms<sup>†</sup> for varint encoding) that *technically* could produce different output with the same meaning, but protobuf-net will always produce the same output currently.

I *am* toying with adding an option to *deliberately* use sub-normal varint forms to avoid some memory shuffling, but that would be opt-in only.

So; as long as you aren't building your binary files by *appending* (protobuf is an appendable format, but obviously all bets are off if you are appending in arbitrary orders), then yes: the data on the wire should be predictable, and you can compare the byte sequence to test for equality.

As a minor note, I would recommend a regular `for` loop here, for efficiency:

```
if (serializedModel.Length != existingBlob.Length)
{
    return false;
}
for(int i = 0 ; i < serializedModel.Length ; i++)
    if(serializedModel[i] != existingBlob[i]) return false;
return true;
```

(if you are *particularly* speed-crazy, you could even use `unsafe` code and compare it as a `int*` or `long*` instead (taking 1/4 or 1/8 of the tests), and just check the last few bytes manually)

You might also consider comparing a *hash* (sha1 etc) instead of byte-by-byte; this would be especially useful for large models, especially if you can store the hashed value along with the original (so you never have to fetch the original existing BLOB - just the existing hash).

---

<sup>†</sup> : specifically, the bit-sequence `10000000` or `00000000` at the "big end" of a varint just means "and more zeros at the big end" (with or without more data to follow), so has no impact on the number; hence any (reasonable) number of `0x80 0x80 0x00` on the end of a varint does not change the result; there is a use-case where-by this could be used to avoid having to move data around, by deliberately using an oversized varint as a length-prefix.